# Nesting expressions in Wiremock

Tags: jsonpath, wiremock, handlebars.java

I am trying to nest expressions in Wiremock and I get an error.  Is it possible to nest a randomValue inside the pickRandom helper?

Example:

I have a wiremock stub that returns: `"{{{pickRandom '{\"test\": \"1\"}' '{\"test\": \"{{randomValue type=\'UUID\'}}\"}'}}}"`

Answer (score 0):

I cannot test this but it might be possible to select the pickRandom Helper value from a list passed as a parameter, e.g.: `{{{pickRandom (jsonPath request.body '$.names')}}}`

```
{{{pickRandom ('{\"test\": \"1\"}' '{\"test\": \"{{randomValue type=\'UUID\'}}\"}')}}}
```

Ref: http://wiremock.org/docs/response-templating/